# Automatically fill the form field with a function but I have an undefined why?

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I would like to automatically fill the form fields with the values that are in the localStorage and with a function , but with this code I have the value undefined in the input of the form. I don't see my error in the code?

code :

```
const dataLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("formsValues");

const dataLocalStorageObjet = JSON.parse(dataLocalStorage);

function fillInInputfieldfromLocalStorage(input) {
  const data = document.querySelector(`#${input}`).setAttribute('value', dataLocalStorageObjet.input);
  return data;  
}

fillInInputfieldfromLocalStorage("name");
```

Comment: What is `dataLocalStorageObjet.input`? And how it works?

Comment: I added the missing code

Comment: Please use a `console.log()` API and share the actual value of `dataLocalStorageObjet` for us.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution :

```
  function remplirChampInputDepuisLocalStorage(input){
  const data = document.querySelector(`#${input}`).value = dataLocalStorageObjet[input];
//  return dataLocalStorageObjet;
```

}